# Open a file with a button then storing the path in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

As the title states, I want to open a file with a browse button then store the file path for later use. I have no issue browsing the file, I just can't get the path to store into a variable. Many thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

import openpyxl
from termcolor import cprint


# initializing tk
root = Tk()
root.title("Tools")
root.geometry("600x300")
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack(side = BOTTOM )

def getFile():
    # open dialog box to select file
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file")


#create button
browsebutton = Button(frame, text="Browse", command=getFile)
browsebutton.pack(side = BOTTOM)

#store the open file path into a variable
path = root.filename
```

Comment: Your code works for me (with minor revisions). When you click the browser button, the path you choose does get saved to `root.filename`. Perhaps you are confused about when that happens? Your last statement is useless since `root.filename` won't be set until the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global(you should avoid global if possible) or use a class

```
def getfile():
          path.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file")

def do_other_work_with_path():
    #your Code here
    print(path.get())

path = StringVar()

#using global
def getfile():
        global path
        path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file")

# or using a class for your whole gui
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent=parent
        self.button=Button(self.parent, text='Browse', command=self.getfile)
        self.button.pack()

    def getfile(self):
        self.path=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file")

    gui=GUI(root)
    #you can also call gui.path with a class
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I apologize if the following sound noobish. I tried the stringvar() method and did a simple print statement for the path using print(path.get()) and it did not work. Isn't this a string that I can print out?

Comment: Actually I need to apologize it looks like you either need another function to do what you with path but you would need something to call this function or you need to use one of the other functions. Maybe I can help you and edit my answer if you tell me when you need the path

Comment: I need to use the path after a file is selected. I use the path with openpyxl to read and edit excel files. I'm obviously not doing this correctly because the only way I can access the path is if I put anything after root.mainloop() Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you create a button and function like `work_with_excel` you should be able to call `path.get()` inside the function

Comment: That's a great idea, don't know how I missed that, I will try that, thank you!!